# Does \expanded replace the \romannumeral trick for expansion?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, programming, texlive-2019

TeXLive 2019 is here :D

One of its awaited features is the new `\expanded` primitive now available in all of the main engines (only available in LuaTeX in previous years) thanks to Joseph Wright.

What we had up to now was:

- Full expansion with `\edef` and the like;
  Pros: expands the entire token list respecting `\protected` (any form thereof) tokens
  Cons: being an assignment operation, it is not itself expandable;
- Partial expansion exploiting `\romannumeral`, which expands tokens while looking for an `⟨integer⟩` and a trailing `⟨optional space⟩`;
  Pros: is expandable, allowing one<sup>1</sup> to write some really interesting macros (including an expandable emulation of the `\expanded` primitive);
  Cons: only expands the “head” of the token list, stopping as soon as it finds an expandable token which does not fit into its argument specification;

`\expanded` gives a nice mix of both, allowing us to get the full expansion of a token list while being itself expandable, apparently covering a great deal of the use-cases of both `\edef` and `\romannumeral`.

Of course `\edef` still is really useful when the expansion of the tokens needs to be stored in a macro, and the produced macro can take arguments normally, which aren't features of `\expanded`.

The `\romannumeral` trick, however, seems to have lost much of it's usefulness with `\expanded`. From what I understand, many situations which required `\romannumeral` to get the full expansion of something, now can use `\expanded` for the same effect with a proper *expansion* primitive.

I know that the answer to the question in the title is “no” because there are a few situations in which `\romannumeral` is still useful. The main one, I think, are undelimited arguments; `\expanded` requires the material to be expanded as a `⟨general text⟩` argument, while `\romannumeral` can be put in the token and act indefinitely, until an unexpandable token is found. Another situation is, of course, when one *really* wants only the head of the token list expanded, then `\romannumeral` is the tool for the job.

But both these situations seem much smaller than the entire scope of using `\romannumeral` for expansion. Thus my question (finally) is: can the expansion trick with `\romannumeral` be replaced mostly everywhere (as an example I can mention the LaTeX3 kernel, which heavily uses this `\romannumeral`-powered expansion)? What other situations require `\romannumeral` for expansion and will not work with `\expanded`?

---

<sup>1</sup>In this case a very particular one :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In many case the `\romannumeral` trick is obsolete, but there are at least two cases where it still is useful.

The first is in that as mentioned in the question it's 'open ended', whereas `\expanded` requires an argument to be grabbed. The second is that `\romannumeral` expansion works through tokens exactly as TeX itself does when typesetting, up to the point it finds some 'payload'. This allows us to deal with any expandable material and then 'look ahead' at the first non-expandable token. An example from `l3galley`:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \galley_par:
  {
    \s__galley_par_omit
    \exp_after:wN \__galley_par_auxi: \exp:w \exp_end_continue_f:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__galley_par_auxi:
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF \s__galley_par_omit
      { \__galley_par_aux:N }
      { \__galley_par_auxii: }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__galley_par_aux:N #1
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnF {#1} { \s__galley_par_omit }
      {
        \__galley_par_auxii:
        #1
      }
  }
```

The `\romannumeral` here is hidden inside `\exp:w`, but the idea is simple. The expansion will continue until some non-expandable token is found. We then 'come back' to a look-ahead, which checks for a token that is exactly equivalent to `\s__galley_par_omit`, a marker for consecutive `\par` tokens. This needs the open-ended nature of `\romannumeral` and the fact that it stops.

It's also worth noting that `\romannumeral` ignores `\protected` status: that shows up above, and would also be handy in implementing for example `\halign` in macros. (This is another place we need a look-ahead.)

---

These aspects are quite specialised, and in most cases do not apply. The bigger barrier to shifting to `\expanded` is that it is only now generally available: it will be many years before it is safe to assume that `\expanded` is safe to use without a fall-back.

Comment: Oh, I completely overlooked the `\protected` macros. I think this would make a nice way to test if a macro is protected. The look ahead thing looks interesting though :)

Comment: @Myself No, it wouldn't and `expl3` already has `\token_if_protected_macro:NTF` :)