# What does ✩ (not ⋆) mean in interface3.pdf?

Tags: expl3, latex3

See the LaTeX 3 programming layer doc here:
https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf

`⋆` seems to indicate whether a macro is expandable; e.g.:

```
\prop_to_keyval:N ⋆
```

But what is `✩`?

```
\prop_map_function:NN ✩
\prop_map_function:cN ✩
```

Comment: Functions with the filled star are fully expandable also with recursive expansion (`f`), those with the hollow star are fully expandable only for `x` or `e` expansion. Now that we have `e` in all engines, the distinction is less important, but there are cases where `f` expansion is still useful.

Comment: Page 6 of interface3 describes what Fully and Restricted expandable functions are.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Happy to accept egreg's comment as an answer.
(Page 6 indeed contains the explanation; it unfortunately looked like the doc for `\cs_to_str:N`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types of “full expansion”, corresponding to three argument types:

- `e` means “expandable full expansion”, corresponding to the primitive `\expanded`
- `x` means “unexpandable full expansion”, corresponding to the trick

  ```
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup <tokens to be expanded>}\x
  ```
- `f` means “recursive expansion“ and is triggered by `\romannumeral`.

Until 2019, `\expanded` was only available in LuaTeX, but with the 2019 release of TeX Live, this new primitive is present in all engines, so the `l3kernel` started to employ it in preference to `f`. See [Does \expanded replace the \romannumeral trick for expansion?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/489063/4427)

The filled star denotes kernel functions that can be used in all three types of full expansion, the hollow star is for functions that do their job only in `e` or `x` expansion, because it's impossible to achieve their final output by recursive `f`-expansion.

As mentioned in the linked thread, `f`-expansion is less needed nowadays that `e`-expansion is available.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that with `\expanded` available, it is possible to turn any 'regular' hollow-star function into a filled-star one: it's only now functions searching unbraced input that might not be 'convertible' to filled-star expandable?

Comment: (Once we _require_ `\expanded` for `expl3`, that is something for the team to look at, of course, as it would simplify things.)